# Switch PC cannot see Router PC?

Tags: windows-xp, networking, router, printer

So I will try explain what is going on. I had to replace a faulty linksys router. I replaced it and here is the problem. The linksys router is connected to a switch. There is one XP PC and one network Printer, which is connected to the switch and one W7 PC which is Wirelessly connected to the linksys router. W7 PC has internet connection but cannot see the network printer anymore. XP PC can see the network printer and also can print on it but there is no internet connection.

Somehow I set up the internet connection on the XP PC (i think that I set up tcp/ip protocol that it get the ip automatically) and there was the internet connection but the connection with the printer was gone. I restarted the router and the switch and then the XP PC was still obtaining the IP automatically but there was no internet connection again and the network printer was still available...

I guess I am missing something here about the configuration or I don't know.. If someone has any idea what is going on..is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The devices on the swich needs to be configured by hand. There is no DHCP inside your switch.

Use a IP-Address in the range of your router for the XP PC.
For the DNS and Gateway use the Router IP-Address.

For example
**If the Router have** 
IP: 192.168.0.0

**XP PC should be configured as followed**
IP = 192.168.0.2
DNS = 192.168.0.0
Default Gateway = 192.168.0.0

**Printer should be configured as followed**
IP = 192.168.0.3
Default Gateway = 192.168.0.0

Comment: Just in case that this do not solve the problem, is there anything else that could be  the problem?